# ffmpeg, stream audio from server via ssh and save to file together

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg

I need stream audio from server and save to file in one time.

I tried this.

```
ssh -p 22 SERVER "ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -b:a 32k -f avi -" | mpv - &>/dev/null 1> file.mp3
```

But it run stream and saves only info from mpv, not stream output.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe some way first save to file and play this file due the saving?

Answer (score 1):

## --stream-record

Use [`--stream-record`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-stream-record) in `mpv`:

```
 ssh -p 22 SERVER "ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -b:a 32k -f mp3 -" | mpv --stream-record=output.mp3 -
```

From the [documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-stream-record):

> There are some glitches with this because it uses FFmpeg's libavformat
> for writing the output file. For example, it's typical that it will
> only work if the output format is the same as the input format. This
> is the case even if it works with the ffmpeg tool. One reason for this
> is that ffmpeg and its libraries contain certain hacks and workarounds
> for these issues, that are unavailable to outside users.

## tee muxer

Or the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

```
 ssh -p 22 SERVER "ffmpeg -f pulse -i default -b:a 32k -f mp3 -" | ffmpeg -y -i - -map 0 -c copy -f tee "output.mp3|[f=mp3]pipe:" | mpv pipe:
```

Less convenient, but possibly more robust and flexible than using `--stream-record`.

I did not test these commands.